# Doctrine ORM - add UniqueConstraint on MappedSuperclass

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

When using Doctrine as ORM, we have simple inheritance structure, with no inheritance strategy specified (creating a new table per each entity). I have a unique constraint which coveres only fields from the super class, but this unique constraint currently has to be defined on the child classes.

Is there a way to move this unique constraint to the super class annotation? It seems that MappedSuperClass annotation does not take any parameters.

Here is the code:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Activity 
{

  /**
   * @var \DateTime
   * @ORM\Column(name="date_start", type="datetime")
   */
  public $dateStart;

  /**
   * @var \DateTime
   * @ORM\Column(name="date_end", type="datetime")
   */
  public $dateEnd;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="rent_activity",
 * uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="rent_activity_unique", columns={ "date_start", "date_end"})}))
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RentActivity extends Activity {

  /**
   * @var float
   * @ORM\Column(name="rent", type="float")
   */
  public $averagePayment;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="other_activity",...)
 */
class OtherActivity extends Activity {

}
```

Is there a way to move the **rent_activity_unique** to he parent class?

In that case the Doctrine system would have to be smart enough to generate a unique constraint per child class in order to evict constraint name conflict.